# Matrix equality $L^T(LL^{T}+\Psi)^{-1}=(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}$

Tags: matrices

> Result: Let $L$ and $\Psi$ be $p\times p$ matrices, where
>   $\Psi=\operatorname{diag}(\psi_1,\dots,\psi_p)$, then
>   $$L^T(LL^{T}+\Psi)^{-1}=(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}$$

I tried to apply the Woodbury identity in the left side, but can't get the expression in right side.
$$L^T(LL^T+\Psi)^{-1}=L^T[\Psi^{-1}-\Psi^{-1}L(I^{-1}+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}]$$
$$=L^T[\Psi^{-1}-\Psi^{-1}L(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}]$$
$$=L^T\Psi^{-1}-L^T\Psi^{-1}L(I+L^T\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^T\Psi^{-1}$$

I don't know how to get it, I tried to apply Woodbury again but didn't help.

Comment: You can commute diagonal matrices. That might help. Do you know anything else about the structure of the matrices?

Comment: @Wintermute No, just it. $L$ doens't have any special structure.

Answer (score 2):

Use $(AB)^{-1}_{}=B^{-1}_{}A_{}^{-1}$ multiple times.

$$L^T(LL^T+\Psi)^{-1}=((L^T)^{-1})^{-1}(LL^T+\Psi)^{-1}=(L+\Psi(L^{T})^{-1})^{-1}=[\Psi(\Psi^{-1}L+(L^{T})^{-1})]^{-1}$$
$$=(\Psi^{-1}L+(L^{T})^{-1})^{-1}\Psi^{-1}=[(L^{T})^{-1}(L^{T}\Psi^{-1}L+I)]^{-1}\Psi^{-1}=(I+L^{T}\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^{T}\Psi^{-1}.$$

Hence 
$$L^T(LL^T+\Psi)^{-1}=(I+L^{T}\Psi^{-1}L)^{-1}L^{T}\Psi^{-1}.$$